# Panel not showing up in roulette game

Tags: java, jpanel, panel

I am working on a roulette game for class and don't know what went wrong. It compiles but when I run it the panel just doesn't show up. It would be great if one of you could take a look at my code. And I know that I could use a loop to do a lot of this stuff but for now I just want to get it working.
Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Layout extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

public static String title = "Roulette Game";
public static Dimension size = new Dimension(610,150);
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
public static JButton spin = new JButton("Spin");
public static int TotalChecked;
public JLabel MoneyLabel = new JLabel("You have $ " + AmountOfMoney);
public JLabel empty = new JLabel ("                       ");
public static int AmountOfMoney = 36;
public static int Random;
public static int MoneyEarned;


//Check whether checkboxes are checked
public static boolean b1;
public static boolean b2;
public static boolean b3;
public static boolean b4;
public static boolean b5;
public static boolean b6;
public static boolean b7;
public static boolean b8;
public static boolean b9;
public static boolean b10;
public static boolean b11;
public static boolean b12;
public static boolean b13;
public static boolean b14;
public static boolean b15;
public static boolean b16;
public static boolean b17;
public static boolean b18;
public static boolean b19;
public static boolean b20;
public static boolean b21;
public static boolean b22;
public static boolean b23;
public static boolean b24;
public static boolean b25;
public static boolean b26;
public static boolean b27;
public static boolean b28;
public static boolean b29;
public static boolean b30;
public static boolean b31;
public static boolean b32;
public static boolean b33;
public static boolean b34;
public static boolean b35;
public static boolean b36;
//Checkboxes
JCheckBox a1 = new JCheckBox("1 ");
JCheckBox a2 = new JCheckBox("2 ");
JCheckBox a3 = new JCheckBox("3 ");
JCheckBox a4 = new JCheckBox("4 ");
JCheckBox a5 = new JCheckBox("5 ");
JCheckBox a6 = new JCheckBox("6 ");
JCheckBox a7 = new JCheckBox("7 ");
JCheckBox a8 = new JCheckBox("8 ");
JCheckBox a9 = new JCheckBox("9 ");
JCheckBox a10 = new JCheckBox("10 ");
JCheckBox a11 = new JCheckBox("11 ");
JCheckBox a12 = new JCheckBox("12 ");
JCheckBox a13 = new JCheckBox("13 ");
JCheckBox a14 = new JCheckBox("14 ");
JCheckBox a15 = new JCheckBox("15 ");
JCheckBox a16 = new JCheckBox("16 ");
JCheckBox a17 = new JCheckBox("17 ");
JCheckBox a18 = new JCheckBox("18 ");
JCheckBox a19 = new JCheckBox("19 ");
JCheckBox a20 = new JCheckBox("20 ");
JCheckBox a21 = new JCheckBox("21 ");
JCheckBox a22 = new JCheckBox("22 ");
JCheckBox a23 = new JCheckBox("23 ");
JCheckBox a24 = new JCheckBox("24 ");
JCheckBox a25 = new JCheckBox("25 ");
JCheckBox a26 = new JCheckBox("26 ");
JCheckBox a27 = new JCheckBox("27 ");
JCheckBox a28 = new JCheckBox("28 ");
JCheckBox a29 = new JCheckBox("29 ");
JCheckBox a30 = new JCheckBox("30 ");
JCheckBox a31 = new JCheckBox("31 ");
JCheckBox a32 = new JCheckBox("32 ");
JCheckBox a33 = new JCheckBox("33 ");
JCheckBox a34 = new JCheckBox("34 ");
JCheckBox a35 = new JCheckBox("35 ");
JCheckBox a36 = new JCheckBox("36 ");

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Game started successfully");
    Layout layout = new Layout();
}

public Layout(){
    super(title);
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(panel);
    spin.addActionListener(this);

    panel.add(a1);
    panel.add(a2);
    panel.add(a3);
    panel.add(a4);
    panel.add(a5);
    panel.add(a6);
    panel.add(a7);
    panel.add(a8);
    panel.add(a9);
    panel.add(a10);
    panel.add(a11);
    panel.add(a12);
    panel.add(a13);
    panel.add(a14);
    panel.add(a15);
    panel.add(a16);
    panel.add(a17);
    panel.add(a18);
    panel.add(a19);
    panel.add(a20);
    panel.add(a21);
    panel.add(a22);
    panel.add(a23);
    panel.add(a24);
    panel.add(a25);
    panel.add(a26);
    panel.add(a27);
    panel.add(a28);
    panel.add(a29);
    panel.add(a30);
    panel.add(a31);
    panel.add(a32);
    panel.add(a33);
    panel.add(a34);
    panel.add(a35);
    panel.add(a36);

    panel.add(spin);
    panel.add(empty);
    panel.add(MoneyLabel);

}



@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    if (event.getSource() == spin) {
        MoneyEarned = 0;
        Random = (int)(Math.random() * ((36) + 1));
        if(TotalChecked == 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, "Please check at least 1 box", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        System.out.println("test button has been clicked");

        if(a1.isSelected()){
            b1 = true;
        }else{
            b1 = false;
        }  

        if(a1.isSelected()){ b1 = true; }else{ b1 = false; }  
        if(a2.isSelected()){ b2 = true; }else{ b2 = false; }  
        if(a3.isSelected()){ b3 = true; }else{ b3 = false; }  
        if(a4.isSelected()){ b4 = true; }else{ b4 = false; }  
        if(a5.isSelected()){ b5 = true; }else{ b5 = false; }  
        if(a6.isSelected()){ b6 = true; }else{ b6 = false; }  
        if(a7.isSelected()){ b7 = true; }else{ b7 = false; }  
        if(a8.isSelected()){ b8 = true; }else{ b8 = false; }  
        if(a9.isSelected()){ b9 = true; }else{ b9 = false; }  
        if(a10.isSelected()){ b10 = true; }else{ b10 = false; }  
        if(a11.isSelected()){ b11 = true; }else{ b11 = false; }  
        if(a12.isSelected()){ b12 = true; }else{ b12 = false; }  
        if(a13.isSelected()){ b13 = true; }else{ b13 = false; }  
        if(a14.isSelected()){ b14 = true; }else{ b14 = false; }  
        if(a15.isSelected()){ b15 = true; }else{ b15 = false; }  
        if(a16.isSelected()){ b16 = true; }else{ b16 = false; }  
        if(a17.isSelected()){ b17 = true; }else{ b17 = false; }  
        if(a18.isSelected()){ b18 = true; }else{ b18 = false; }  
        if(a19.isSelected()){ b19 = true; }else{ b19 = false; }  
        if(a20.isSelected()){ b20 = true; }else{ b20 = false; }  
        if(a21.isSelected()){ b21 = true; }else{ b21 = false; }  
        if(a22.isSelected()){ b22 = true; }else{ b22 = false; }  
        if(a23.isSelected()){ b23 = true; }else{ b23 = false; }  
        if(a24.isSelected()){ b24 = true; }else{ b24 = false; }  
        if(a25.isSelected()){ b25 = true; }else{ b25 = false; }  
        if(a26.isSelected()){ b26 = true; }else{ b26 = false; }  
        if(a27.isSelected()){ b27 = true; }else{ b27 = false; }  
        if(a28.isSelected()){ b28 = true; }else{ b28 = false; }  
        if(a29.isSelected()){ b29 = true; }else{ b29 = false; }  
        if(a30.isSelected()){ b30 = true; }else{ b30 = false; }  
        if(a31.isSelected()){ b31 = true; }else{ b31 = false; }  
        if(a32.isSelected()){ b32 = true; }else{ b32 = false; }  
        if(a33.isSelected()){ b33 = true; }else{ b33 = false; }  
        if(a34.isSelected()){ b34 = true; }else{ b34 = false; }  
        if(a35.isSelected()){ b35 = true; }else{ b35 = false; }  
        if(a36.isSelected()){ b36 = true; }else{ b36 = false; }  

        if(b1 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b2 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b3 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b4 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b5 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b6 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b7 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b8 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b9 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b10 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b11 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b12 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b13 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b14 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b15 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b16 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b17 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b18 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b19 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b20 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b21 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b22 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b23 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b24 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b25 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b26 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b27 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b28 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b29 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b30 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b31 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b32 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b33 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b34 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b35 == true) { TotalChecked++; }
        if(b36 == true) { TotalChecked++; }

        if(Random == 1){ if(b1 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 2){ if(b2 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 3){ if(b3 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 4){ if(b4 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 5){ if(b5 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 6){ if(b6 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 7){ if(b7 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 8){ if(b8 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 9){ if(b9 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 10){ if(b10 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 11){ if(b11 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 12){ if(b12 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 13){ if(b13 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 14){ if(b14 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 15){ if(b15 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 16){ if(b16 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 17){ if(b17 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 18){ if(b18 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 19){ if(b19 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 20){ if(b20 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 21){ if(b21 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 22){ if(b22 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 23){ if(b23 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 24){ if(b24 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 25){ if(b25 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 26){ if(b26 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 27){ if(b27 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 28){ if(b28 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 29){ if(b29 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 30){ if(b30 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 31){ if(b31 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 32){ if(b32 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 33){ if(b33 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 34){ if(b34 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 35){ if(b35 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if(Random == 36){ if(b36 == true){ AmountOfMoney = AmountOfMoney - TotalChecked + 36; MoneyEarned = 36 - TotalChecked ; JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Congratulations you won $" + (36-TotalChecked)); }   }
        if (MoneyEarned == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You have lost $" + (TotalChecked));
        }
        MoneyLabel.setText("You have $ " + AmountOfMoney);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Take `setVisible(true);` and put it at the end of `Layout`s constructor

Comment: Omg you must have sore hands from typing all them variables... please look into arrays

Comment: How to type all of those arrays in 10 seconds... Excel

Answer (score 1):

Call `setVisible` last, after you have established the UI

```
public Layout(){
    super(title);
    // Use pack, it's safer, but do this JUST before you call setVisible...
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    // Move me...
    //setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    add(panel);
    spin.addActionListener(this);

    //...

    panel.add(spin);
    panel.add(empty);
    panel.add(MoneyLabel);

    // To here
    setVisible(true);

}
```